# *ngFor with `{}` blank objects are referring to single reference when collection defined on template

Tags: angular, data-binding, ngfor

I've requirement where I'm displaying series of text box with Initial blank data. So for the same I created one array with 3 blank `[{},{},{}]`. Then I did loop over each element and displayed on view using `*ngFor`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of [{},{},{}]">
    {{item.Id}}
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.Id">
</div>
```

Above render my all text boxes correctly, but when I try to change any of input element, all textboxes refers to same reference.

I'm expecting to change the particular `item` object `Id` property. I know I can move array declaration inside my component class(though that's solves my issue), I'm curious to know whats wrong with array declaration on template?

[**Problem Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/gbhfxFk5kDIArYROEnYQ?p=preview)

Comment: This feels like an XY Problem to me.  You've already mentioned that you can solve it by moving the array into your class, and in fact you would need to do that *anyway*, in order to do anything *useful* with these input boxes, so it's not clear why you are trying to solve this at all.

Comment: @Claies I know it can be solved by other way, should I delete this question then..? Its confuses me why it works with other way around, so I thought better I should ask a question..

Comment: It might still reveal some interesting information about inner workings of Angular, or even a bug.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes, it seems like a bug in template engine/compiler.. Lets see till tomorrow.. anybody can help me with this.. otherwise I'll add issue on github..

Answer (score 2):

Object instances created in a template using identical object literal syntax are reused AFAIK, therefore 3x the same object.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of [{},{},{}]">
```

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
```

with

```
items:[{},{},{}];
```

should work, because in TS 3 new objects will be created.

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/5jTYfjePcW2i1N3lzksv?p=preview)

Comment: Also then why `[{Id: ''},{Id: ''},{Id: ''}]` it works well on template? As per your answer, my suggested should also wouldn't have work

Comment: It's intersting. If I pass it to an event handler, they are also not considered equal http://plnkr.co/edit/b7ZAZBIt7T8oyocyTMa5?p=preview

Comment: If I pass them one, by one, they are identical http://plnkr.co/edit/ZfFGQd9dEtvdpKMYOBj9?p=preview

Comment: one more twist `[{},{Id: 1},{}]` make only middle one as unique, other blank object shares only single object memory reference

Comment: I guess it's only reusing `{}` literals not all literals that have the same content.

Comment: I don't know who did it.. :( If I do it, I'd have comment

Comment: @PankajParkar didn't expect it was you. Quite often it helps to post an invitation to explain the downvote.

Comment: We can simplify our template like `{{ [{id:''},{},{}] }}` or any property binding that will have effect on generation updateRenderer function and take a look at this function https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.x/packages/compiler/src/view_compiler/view_compiler.ts#L711-L714

Comment: If we pass it to event handler like in one of examples above then it is passing directly http://take.ms/pRILO

Comment: I think that's because we can write `(click)="someUndefinedFn()"` and don't get any errors from compiler even we don't have `someUndefinedFn` in our component(excluding aot because factory is typechecked)

Answer (score -1):

You haven't declared the `item.id` property.

The following code would work:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of [{id: ''},{id: ''},{id: ''}]">
  {{item.id}}
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.id">
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense, if I shift the same `items` object declaration to component it does work, check plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cwTEeb1yejPDjTWOicdw?p=preview). There we don't have to have `id` prop to defined on `items` element.. Angular will create it for us as an when you add value in `input` box..